# How to make a loop of variable of same name and get comma separated value in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string of values which are comma separated i want to run a loop and assign first value of all three variable in a single String. For example in this scenario i want output as

```
o1v1 o2v1 o3v1
o1v2 o2v2 o3v2
o1v3 o2v3 o3v3
```

Is there any possibility of this ? Here is my method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String option1 = "o1v1,o1v2,o1v3";
        String option2 = "o2v1,o2v2,o2v3";
        String option3 = "o3v1,o3v2,o3v3";

        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++){


        }

    }
```

Comment: You may want to look into `String.split()`

Comment: bt it will return me the array of this value . and how can I loop the option 1 option2 option3 through one for loop

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Try without loop and using `String#split`

Comment: will option1,  option2 and option3 always have equal number of values ?

Comment: because i want to add the first value of each variable in one string and then 2nd value of all variables in second string similarly for 3rd

Comment: @dora yes. they have equal num of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
String option1 = "o1v1,o1v2,o1v3";
String option2 = "o2v1,o2v2,o2v3";
String option3 = "o3v1,o3v2,o3v3";
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] options1 = option1.split(",");
String[] options2 = option2.split(",");
String[] options3 = option3.split(",");

for(int i=0; i<options1.length; i++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(options1[i]);
    sb.append(options2[i]);
    sb.append(options3[i]);
    output.add(sb.toString());


}

System.out.println(output);

}
```

The output list will have all the strings you need

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is that instead of storing in three separate strings you could store it in a single string array. It would be easier in looping like this:

```
    String[] options = {"o1v1,o1v2,o1v3",
                        "o2v1,o2v2,o2v3",
                        "o3v1,o3v2,o3v3"};
```

OR

```
    String[] options = new String[]{option1, option2, option3};
```

Now instead of using a for loop you could use an easier for-each loop. as illustrated below:

```
    for(String option : options){
       String[] opts = option.split(",");
       for(String opt : opts){
          System.out.print(opt+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
```

In the above code you do not have the think of the size of the array `options` and the number of sub-strings it is to contain.

**Edit 1**

After you comment I am changing this for-each loop to a new code;

```
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String option : options){
       String[] opts = option.split(",");
       String temp = "";
       for(String opt : opts){
         temp = temp + opt + " ";
       }
       output.add(temp)
    }
```

Now from your variable `output` you can create the variable like:

```
String outOption1 = output.get(0);
.....
.....
```

This I hope will solve your problem.

Comment: m getting compile time error at this line String[] opts = String.split(option, ",");

Comment: @user2142786 I have corrected the code. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user2142786 I have edited the answer to include variable `option1`, `option2` and `option3`

Comment: can i get the value of these lines in a variable like after for index=0;(String option : options){
       String[] opts = option.split(",");
       for(String opt : opts){
          System.out.print(opt+" ");
       } optionindex++ = opt}

Comment: i want these three lines in three separate variables

Comment: Did you see my edited answer? I created `String[] options = new String[]{option1, option2, option3};` where the options contain all the three Strings

Comment: @user2142786 I have edited my answer to accommodate what you have written in your comment

Comment: i just notice it.. logic is not working correctly. i want my output as o1v1 o2v1 o3v1
o1v2 o2v2 o3v2
o1v3 o2v3 o3v3 and it is printing same as input

Comment: @user2142786 Could you clarify this thing in you question as the formatting is not preserved in the comments.

Comment: if you look at the question i mentioned there i want output as .... now i just want to store these 3 lines in 3 variables

Comment: @user2142786 I have edited my answer to accommodate that only. `String outOption1 = output.get(0);
.....
.....`

Comment: @user2142786 the `.....` means like `String outOption2 = output.get(1);` and so on.

Comment: @user2142786 do you mean to say that the program dynamically decides the variable name like `option1`, `option2`, `.....`, `optionN`?

Comment: Hi Blip.. Thanks for your help.. i resolve using this ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] options1 = option1.split(",");
String[] options2 = option2.split(",");
String[] options3 = option3.split(",");

for(int i=0; i<options1.length; i++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(options1[i]);
    sb.append(options2[i]);
    sb.append(options3[i]);
    output.add(sb.toString());


}

System.out.println(output);

}

Answer (score -1):

Are all the option strings that same format? If so, you already know the indices where you want to split them.

```
String firstPlace=option1.substring(0, 5)+option2.substring(0, 5)+option3.substring(0,5);
```

prints out "o1v1,o2v1,o3v1", and you could repeat with different indices for each one you wanted.